# Which one is correct "they didn't" or "they don't" when using "for" afterwards

Tags: phrases, verbs, conjugation

I'm confused whether I should use "didn't" or "don't" in the following sentence:

> Makki and Mattsun didn't have time to execute their plan, for two not-so-soon-expected guests are suddenly making an outstanding entrance!

The "outstanding entrance" is happening as we speak, so would it be better to use "don't"?

Answer (score 1):

*Didn't*, i.e. ***did** not* is in past tense and does not agree with the rest of the sentence and therefore, you would need to tweak the second half for it to properly fit:

> Makki and Mattsun didn't have time to execute their plan, for two not-so-soon-expected guests suddenly made an outstanding entrance!

However, since the event is ongoing, you may want to replace "didn't" with "don't" instead:

> Makki and Mattsun don't have time to execute their plan, for two not-so-soon-expected guests are suddenly *(or currently)* making an outstanding entrance!

Comment: Thank you for your help  ! It makes much more sense to me now.